# ASP.NET Web Api точка в запросе

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте. Проблема в том, что при посылке запрос, например, http://site.com/api/namecontroller/Петров П.П., то он это воспринимается, как URL, а не как переменная, что можно сделать, чтобы приложение понимало, что это параметр?

P.S. Параметры передаются в такой форме: namecontroller/param1/param2/param3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так:

```
http://site.com/api/namecontroller?param_name=Петров П.П.
```

соответственно, если параметров несколько:

```
<...>controller?param_name=Петров П.П.&param2_name=param2&param3_name=param3
```

Comment: А если структура такая: namecontroller/param1/param2/param3/../?

Comment: параметры через & разделяются 

http://site.com/api/namecontroller?param_name=Петров П.П.&param2=1&param3=Ученик

Comment: В mvc есть своя таблица маршрутов, в т.ч. для api, с которой ассоциируются передаваемые параметры, просто в таблицу маршрутов надо внести изменения, чтобы он понимал такие "красивые" Url http://site.ru/controller/action/Петров%20П

Comment: Маршрут есть и прекрасно работает, но допустим я передаю: /api/anynamecontroller/1/0/1020/Язык/321/Петров А.В./42/10/

И мне вернется 404, потому что Петров А.В./ воспринимается, как URL. Пробую переделать, как передачу параметров, но ощущение, что будет такая же штука, но посмотрим.

Comment: проблема решаема, но не на уровне mvc маршрутов, а на уровне iis хэндлеров: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis
имхо, проще переделать по "старые добрые" url-параметры